# Unable to exclude Java files during Sonar Execution

Tags: java, jenkins, sonarqube

I get below error while executing my sonarqube scanner using Jenkins.
SonarQube= Version 5.1.1 - LGPL
Sonar Scanner= Version 2.6

Please let me know how to exclude the Java files for a particular module in Multi Module Ant project.
Sonar properties

```
sonar.projectKey=PROJECT
sonar.projectName=PROJECT
sonar.projectVersion=1
sonar.sources=.
sonar.modules=PROJECTb2bbackoffice,PROJECTb2bcockpits,PROJECTb2bcore,PROJECTb2bfacades,PROJECTb2binitialdata,PROJECTb2bpricefactory,PROJECTb2bstorefront,PROJECTb2btest,PROJECTb2bordermanagement

module-one.sonar.projectName=PROJECTb2bstorefront
module-one.sonar.sources=.

module-two.sonar.projectName=PROJECTb2bcore
module-two.sonar.sources=.

module-three.sonar.projectName=PROJECTb2bbackoffice
module-three.sonar.sources=.

module-four.sonar.projectName=PROJECTb2bcockpits
module-four.sonar.sources=.

module-five.sonar.projectName=PROJECTb2bfacades
module-five.sonar.sources=.

module-six.sonar.projectName=PROJECTb2binitialdata
module-six.sonar.sources=.

module-seven.sonar.projectName=PROJECTb2bpricefactory
module-seven.sonar.sources=.

module-eight.sonar.projectName=PROJECTb2btest
module-eight.sonar.sources=.

module-nine.sonar.projectName=PROJECTb2bordermanagement
module-nine.sonar.sources=.
module-nine.sonar.exclusions=PROJECTb2bordermanagement/src/com/PROJECT/b2b/ordermanagement/actions/order/cancel/*.java,PROJECTb2bordermanagement/src/com/PROJECT/b2b/ordermanagement/impl/*.java

ERROR: Error during SonarQube Scanner execution
org.sonar.squidbridge.api.AnalysisException: SonarQube is unable to analyze file : '/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Project/module9/src/com/module/b2b/ordermanagement/actions/order/cancel/ProcessOrderCancellationAction.java'
    at org.sonar.java.ast.AstScanner.simpleScan(AstScanner.java:114)
    at org.sonar.java.ast.AstScanner.scan(AstScanner.java:75)
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the full stacktrace, including the "Caused by" section.

Answer (score 0):

you can try below `sonar-property` :

```
sonar.projectKey=Template
sonar.projectName=Template
sonar.projectVersion=1.0.0
sonar.sources=src/app
sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8
sonar.exclusions=**/node_modules/**,**/*.spec.ts
sonar.tests=src/app
sonar.test.inclusions=**/*.spec.ts
sonar.ts.lcov.reportpath=coverage/coverage.lcov
sonar.ts.tslintconfigpath=tslint.json
```

Comment: Can you please be more specific related to above. I used exclusions already not sure why it is not accepting.

Answer (score 0):

I have not used the configuration file in a while. But in the maven pom I would do it slithy different. But I try to adapt your example.

```
module-nine.sonar.projectName=PROJECTb2bordermanagement
module-nine.sonar.sources=.
module-nine.sonar.exclusions=src/com/PROJECT/b2b/ordermanagement/**/*
```

If you use `**` all sub folders will be excluded. I just used them as explanation. You may replace them again with your specific path.